# Dispatcher in smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, action, code

I want to implement **dispatcher** in a smart contract. I research about this and understand theoretically but I am not getting practically. Exactly why the dispatcher is to be used? The basic thing I got that we need an apply action handler which checks code and receiver. But I want to know the exact need and some useful links for simple understanding if possible. Also any tutorials. How to implement dispatcher in smart contract? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you don't need to implement dispatcher by yourself. `[[eosio::action]]` and `[[eosio::on_notify]]` will generate a proper action dispatcher automatically. There were some security accidents by writing incomplete action dispatcher. If you don't know what you are doing exactly, it's better to rely on automatic generation of action dispatcher by `eosio-cpp`.

Basically, EOSIO calls `apply()` function by default for every action. You can consider it like `main()` in normal program. It is an entry point of executing an action. `apply()` function instantiates your contract class (You should've written classes inheriting from `eosio::contract`), and deserializes `name` and `data` fields in action. `name` indicates the name which this action wants to call like `transfer` in `eosio::token` and `data` are arguments like `(from, to, quantity, memo)` needed to be passed to function. By these information, `apply()` will call a proper function and pass arguments to it.

Refer to [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/a6b8d3fc289d46f4612588cdd7223a3d549238f6/libraries/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/dispatcher.hpp#L123-L133) to understand how generated `apply()` looks like.

Comment: Okay got your point. So, even If I don't implement dispatcher separately, there is no concern of security. But still, why dispatchers are used by others then?

Comment: Because earlier `eosio-cpp` didn't support automatic generation of `apply()`. If code that is written recently has manual action dispatcher, its writer may not know the latest changes of eosio.cdt. :)

Comment: Got it.Thank you!